# Serialization of 'Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOConnection' is not allowed

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, maatwebsite-excel

I'm working on a project
and I made an exportable class
this is the class

- I'm sending a query to exportal tyope of 'Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder'

```
 <?php

namespace App\Exports;

use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromQuery;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\Exportable;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithMapping;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadings;

class ExcelExport implements FromQuery, WithMapping, WithHeadings
{
   use Exportable;

   private $query;

   public function __construct($query)
   {
       $this->query = $query;
   }

   public function query()
   {
       return $this->query;
   }

   public function headings():array
   {
       $return = [
           'H1',
           'H2',
       ];

       return $return;
   }

   public function map($row):array
   {
       $return = [];
       foreach ($row->relation as $rel) {
           $return[] = $rel->column;
       }
       return $return;
   }
}
```

and call it into my controller as

```
public function export(Request $request, string $type = 'excel')
    {
        // returns Builder
        $query = $this->service->findByReportable($request, 1);
        
        $file = new ExcelExportLead($query);


        if ($file){
            switch (strtolower($type)) {
                case 'pdf':
                    $file_name = 'export-' . time() . '.pdf';
                    // OriginExcel refers to 'Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel'
                    return $file::queue($file, $file_name, OriginExcel::DOMPDF);
                    break;
                
                default:
                    $file_name = 'export-' . time() . '.xls';
                    return $file->queue($file_name);
                    break;
            }
            
        } else{
            return back()->withErrors(__('common.Sorry But there Was an issue in exporting Data please try again'));
        }
```

But there the error appeared is 'Serialization of 'Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOConnection' is not allowed'

i don't know how to solve it I've used `SerializesModels` but it didn't fix the issue

Answer (score 4):

Serialization it's a tool where you encode a variable/object into a text (or binary) representation to then move that variable to another thread/process.

The underlying problem it's that the Builder object has a PDOConnection attribute (the connection to the database) and those objects by definition can't be serialized, as they are usually a file descriptor in the operating system that can't be moved to another process/thread.

The solution should go along the lines of either

- Sending the query as a string to ExcelExport using the builder->toSql() method
- Encoding the query in some other way (IE anourvalar/eloquent-serialize https://packagist.org/packages/anourvalar/eloquent-serialize).

Comment: the unserialize package seems to work well for me. thanks!